# date Subquery PHP and Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Following is my sql query with included subquery. Essentially I'm looking to obtain the most recent meter readings for our equipment for a given month and year. I know it's in my subquery where the issue is coming up but I don't know how to properly fix it.

Following is result if I delete the subquery and just select equipment with meter readings for that month.

```
eid eqid    name                    pid  hours  date
70  C1  KOMATSU WA250 3YD BUCKET    27  1176    2013-10-07
70  C1  KOMATSU WA250 3YD BUCKET    27  1195    2013-10-28
70  C1  KOMATSU WA250 3YD BUCKET    27  1178    2013-10-14
73  C11 KOMATSU PC200 EXCAVATOR     27  1080    2013-10-14
73  C11 KOMATSU PC200 EXCAVATOR     27  1099    2013-10-28
73  C11 KOMATSU PC200 EXCAVATOR     27  1078    2013-10-07
92  C4  CATERPILLAR 304D MINI EX    27  646     2013-10-14
92  C4  CATERPILLAR 304D MINI EX    27  645     2013-10-07
92  C4  CATERPILLAR 304D MINI EX    27  649     2013-10-28
58  E14 BOBCAT-ATV 2300 Utility     8   522     2013-10-31
61  E17 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            40  943     2013-10-10
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1790    2013-10-30
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1789    2013-10-29
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1777    2013-10-13
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1772    2013-10-07
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1777    2013-10-13
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1772    2013-10-04
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1772    2013-10-07
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1772    2013-10-04
67  E23 BOBCAT SKID STEER           27  1178    2013-10-28
```

Following is result of full query including subquery.

```
92  C4  CATERPILLAR 304D MINI EX    27  649    2013-10-28
61  E17 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            40  943    2013-10-10
62  E18 SKYTRAK FORKLIFT            5   1790   2013-10-30
```

Following is query I am using.

```
SELECT e.eid, e.eqid, e.name, m.pid, m.hours, m.date FROM meter m
JOIN equipment e ON m.eid = e.eid
WHERE MONTH(date) = $month
AND YEAR(date) = $year
AND m.date = (SELECT MAX(m2.date) FROM meter m2 WHERE m2.eid = m.eid)
ORDER BY e.eqid ASC
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT***
I would have never gotten there Sebas. I had to change one thing and it worked perfectly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.eid, e.eqid, e.name, m.pid, m.hours, m.date 
FROM equipment e
JOIN (
    SELECT eid, MAX(date) as date
    FROM meter
    WHERE MONTH(date) = $month
    AND YEAR(date) = $year
    GROUP BY eid
) maxdate ON maxdate.eid = e.eid
JOIN meter m ON m.eid = e.eid AND m.date = maxdate.date
ORDER BY e.eqid ASC
```

Comment: please define more accurately what you're calling `our equipment` and how it is mapped to your database.

Comment: mention the result you expect to get?

Comment: Two or more of those first three or four columns are all redundant, right?

Comment: Not necessarily redundant - but that our employees aren't very familiar with the system as of yet and put multiple entries in. I'll have to put a check in there for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing out the fields of each table, I figured the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.eid, e.eqid, e.name, m.pid, m.hours, m.date 
FROM 
    equipment e
    JOIN (
        SELECT eid, MAX(date)  date
        FROM meter
        WHERE 
            MONTH(date) = $month
        AND YEAR(date) = $year
        GROUP BY eid
    ) maxdate ON maxdate.eid = e.eid
    JOIN meter m ON m.eid = e.eid AND m.date = maxdate.date
ORDER BY e.eqid ASC
```

Comment: Just one minor change to return MAX(date) as date. Thank you - I would've never gotten there.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```sql
SELECT e.eid, e.eqid, e.name, m.pid, m.hours, m.date
  FROM 
(
  SELECT eid, MAX(date) date
    FROM meter
   WHERE date BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND LAST_DAY('2013-10-01')
   GROUP BY eid
) q JOIN meter m 
    ON q.eid = m.eid 
   AND q.date = m.date JOIN equipment e
    ON q.eid = e.eid
 ORDER BY e.eid
```

**Note:** make sure you have an index on `date`. Don't apply any functions (`MONTH()` and such) to this columns in `WHERE` clause because it prevents from using any index you might have on it effectively causing full table scan.

Sample output:

```
| EID | EQID |                     NAME | PID | HOURS |       DATE |
|-----|------|--------------------------|-----|-------|------------|
|  58 |  E14 |  BOBCAT-ATV 2300 Utility |   8 |   522 | 2013-10-31 |
|  61 |  E17 |         SKYTRAK FORKLIFT |  40 |   943 | 2013-10-10 |
|  62 |  E18 |         SKYTRAK FORKLIFT |   5 |  1790 | 2013-10-30 |
|  67 |  E23 |        BOBCAT SKID STEER |  27 |  1178 | 2013-10-28 |
|  70 |   C1 | KOMATSU WA250 3YD BUCKET |  27 |  1195 | 2013-10-28 |
|  73 |  C11 |  KOMATSU PC200 EXCAVATOR |  27 |  1099 | 2013-10-28 |
|  92 |   C4 | CATERPILLAR 304D MINI EX |  27 |   649 | 2013-10-28 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c68a4/1)** demo

Comment: Also works very well, although it does pick up 2 entries for EID 62.

Comment: @hatchet145 The query itself is OK. That was a typo in sample data in sqlfiddle (I left two identical rows in equipment table while deducing your schema). Fixed.

Comment: @hatchet145 And again don't use functions with columns you use for filtering in where clause. Rewrite those conditions to be able to benefit from using an index